# How can I align multiple line plot titles?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Currently I use plotly and it looks not so nice when I use mutliple line titles, it is not aligned. Is there a way to align them properly?

This is how it looks like right now:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
fig = px.line(s, title='This is a fantasy dataset <br> Why is this line not aligned with the text above?')
fig.show
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are using a whitepace after `<br>`. Do you have what you want after deleting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space before `Why`, removing that will put the line aligned to top line.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
fig = px.line(s, title='This is a fantasy dataset <br>Why is this line not aligned with the text above?')
fig.show()
```

After `<br />`, there should not be a space.

This outputs as -

[image]